# Google Analytics API keywords

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I use the [google analytics example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) and I'd like to get list of my keywords. Sorry I am very new to analytics API and couldn't find it the reference. Here is the code copied from there:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response);

 // Initializes an Analytics Reporting API service object.
function initializeAnalytics()
{
}
// Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
function getReport($analytics) {
  $VIEW_ID = "xxxx";
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
 // Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs the number of sessions for the last seven days for the given view but I would like to get the keywords instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `dimensions` parameter to your API request. Something like

```
//Create the Dimensions object.
$keyword = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$keyword->setName("ga:keyword");
///...
// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
// Here is an addition
$request->setDimensions(array($keyword)); 

$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
```

You can find more samples at the Analytics dev site: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples

please keep in mind that in this way you'll only get the data for paid keywords since organic keywords are not tracked in Analytics in most cases.